# insert query generates QueryEvaluationException

Tags: graphdb

I have a script that works when i run it in the local instance of graphdb.
But when i try to use it on the online graphdb at https://cloud.ontotext.com/, i get a `org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException` but nothing indicating which part of the script that caused it.

The only change from the script that works locally, is the

`SERVICE <https://rdf.ontotext.com/4136450524/pedtermsDB/repositories/pedagogyrepo>{`

which was

`SERVICE <http://localhost:7200/rdf-bridge/1967855032375>{`

Any help is appreciated.

The script:

```
PREFIX spif: <http://spinrdf.org/spif#>
PREFIX pdb:<http://example.org/pedtermsDB/>
# CLEAR GRAPH <http://example.org/pedtermsDB/>
# INSERT query that maps the raw RDF data from OntoRefine to user-specified
# RDF data (different IRIs, types, property names and dates as date-typed literals)
# and inserts the data into the current GraphDB repository.
INSERT { graph <http://example.org/pedtermsDB/> {  
 ?subtermIRI a pdb:SubTerm ;
    pdb:label ?subterm;
    pdb:replyList ?sb_id;
    pdb:hasParent ?termIRI.
 ?termIRI a pdb:Term ;
    pdb:label ?term;
    pdb:replyList ?sb_id;
    pdb:topic ?topicIRI.
 ?topicIRI a pdb:Topic;      
    pdb:label ?topic;
    pdb:mapping ?sb_topic;
    pdb:replyList ?sb_id;
    pdb:subject ?subjectIRI.
# ?sb_topicIRI a pdb:StudyBotTopic;  
#    pdb:mapping ?term;
#    pdb:label ?sb_topic.
 ?subjectIRI a pdb:Subject ;
    pdb:label ?subject;
    pdb:field ?fieldIRI. 
 ?fieldIRI a pdb:Field;
    pdb:label ?field;
    pdb:faculty ?facultyIRI.       
?facultyIRI a pdb:Faculty;
    pdb:label ?faculty;
}
} where {
# Uses SERVICE to fetch the raw RDF data from OntoRefine
SERVICE <https://rdf.ontotext.com/4136450524/pedtermsDB/repositories/pedagogyrepo>{
    ?termRow a pdb:Row; 
    pdb:rowNumber ?termRowNumber.
    OPTIONAL {?termRow pdb:term ?term}
    OPTIONAL {?termRow pdb:sb_id ?sb_id}
    OPTIONAL {?termRow pdb:sb_topic ?sb_topic}
    OPTIONAL {?termRow pdb:subterm ?subterm}
     OPTIONAL {?termRow pdb:topic ?topic}  
    ?termRow pdb:subject ?subject. 
    ?termRow pdb:field ?field.
    ?termRow pdb:faculty ?faculty.

     BIND(iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/terms/", ?term)) as ?termIRI)
     BIND(iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/subterms/", ?subterm)) as ?subtermIRI)
   # BIND(iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/studybotTopics/", ?sb_topic)) as ?sb_topicIRI)
   # BIND(IF(?topic=?term,iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/topics/", ?topic)),"") as ?topicIRI)
     BIND(iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/topics/", ?topic)) as ?topicIRI)
     BIND(iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/subjects/", ?subject)) as ?subjectIRI)
     BIND(iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/fields/", ?field)) as ?fieldIRI)
     BIND(iri(concat("http://example.org/pedtermsDB/faculties/", ?faculty)) as ?facultyIRI)    
}
}
```

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted that link, could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different types of SPARQL endpoints mixed in your query:

GraphDB endpoint - the repository endpoint serving indexed RDF triples:

- http://localhost:7200/repositories/repositories/pedagogyrepo - the local endpoint
- https://rdf.ontotext.com/4136450524/pedtermsDB/repositories/pedagogyrepo - the cloud endpoint

OntoRefine endpoint - virtual endpoint to serve OpenRefine's internal tabular model

- http://localhost:7200/rdf-bridge/1967855032375 - the local endpoint
- https://*rdf-bridge// - the cloud endpoint created for this project

You have to find what's the correct OntoRefine endpoint on the cloud through the Workbench interface.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, there is nothing wrong with the query, except the following line:

`SERVICE <https://rdf.ontotext.com/4136450524/pedtermsDB/repositories/pedagogyrepo>{` where I am using the wrong endpoint?

Comment: I made the repository public, and now it says :
"No statements added or removed."
So i believe i have the correct endpoint.
I guess next step is to figure out why nothing has been added?